# Permanent exit button on Excel ribbon

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel workbook that contains a couple hundred tabs that are all very hidden unless needed.  I have it set up so that the user can select a data source from a main sheet and it transfers them to the specific sheet they need.  Then as they finish their task they return to the main sheet and all is hidden again.  What I need is a way to attach a command button to the ribbon so that it is always there and hides everything but the main sheet.

I have worked with put a button on each sheet and even tried a floating form that stays in the corner.  Although these are answers I would prefer to just attach a button to the ribbon and forget about it.  But how do you dynamically create a button in the ribbon that will transfer with the workbook so that every user on any computer will have the button available?

Comment: Rather than a button, use the **QAT**

Comment: You can't create ribbon controls in VBA, but if you use the `CommandBars` API via `Application.CommandBars` it'll create your button under an "add-ins" ribbon tab. Create the button in the workbook's `Workbook_Open` event handler and it will show up when that workbook is opened. A good idea is to also remove the button when the workbook is closed.

Comment: I explored this also, the issue here is that I can't find anything about dynamically creating a add-in that can run a VBA code.  Add-ins are prepackage plug & plays that have to be installed or activated.

Comment: See http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html for how to create a ribbon customization which is attached to your workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around by creating a custom tab and buttons for my workbook. It creates the tab as the workbooks opens and removes it when you close the book.

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

```
Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

hFile = FreeFile
user = Environ("Username")
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI      xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  <mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:qat/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      <mso:tab id='reportTab' label='Pats Tools' insertBeforeQ='mso:TabFormat'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='reportGroup1' label='Month' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Months1' label='Previous' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='AccessTableEvents'      onAction='MonthPrevious.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Months2' label='Current' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='AccessListEvents'      onAction='MonthCurrent.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Months3' label='Next' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='AccessTableEvents'      onAction='MonthNext.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Months4' label='All' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='AccessTableEvents'      onAction='AllMonths.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='reportGroup2' label='Properties' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Properties1' label='All' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='AllProperties.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Properties2' label='Name1' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='Name1.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Properties3' label='Name2' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='Name2.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Properties4' label='Name3' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='Name3.ClearSheet'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Properties5' label='Name4' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='Name4.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='Properties6' label='Name5' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='Name5.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='reportGroup4' label='Edit Task' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='ActionButton1' label='Type' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='AddTypemod.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='ActionButton2' label='Section' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='AddSectionMod.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='ActionButton3' label='Empty' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='BlogHomePage'      onAction='CedarCreek.calling'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      </mso:tab>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    </mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:customUI>"

ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")

Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
Print #hFile, ribbonXML
Close hFile

End Sub
```

Comment: a note: you can line break in VBA with an underscore instead of "& vbNewLine" at the end of the line and start the next line with "&" instead of "ribbonXML = ribbonXML + ".  It's less noisy to look at, but there is a total line limitation.  Here is an example discussion:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422064/break-a-long-sql-vba-statement-into-multiple-lines